# Magento 2.3.3 Install sample data error on setup upgrade

Tags: setup-upgrade, sample-data, magento2.3.3

I got the following error on `setup:upgrade` after installing sample data in **Magento 2.3.3**

Error is thrown on Module `Magento_CatalogSampleData`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /var/www/html/mage233/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3985 in /var/www/html/mage233/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some transactio...', '/var/www/html/m...', 3985, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/mage233/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3985): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/mage233/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61
```

**I also tried with reset and re-install sample data but no success.**

```
php bin/magento sampledata:reset
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer to this. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_sample-data.html

Comment: @DhadukMitesh not found any solution from devdoc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run reindex data command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```